# Изменить оформление меню одним кликом

Tags: java, android, textview, expandablelistview, drawable

Боковое меню выражено через `TextView`:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/list_group_title"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/head"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

В `MainActivity` по нажатию на кнопку выполняется действие:

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
            tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.minus);
            return true;
        default:

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Которое меняет оформление `TextView` меню с `head` на `minus`. Все работает, но меняется лишь самый верхний, первый раздел меню, остальные остаются прежнего фона - `head`. В чем может быть проблема? Ведь по сути я методом `setBackgroundResource` меняю все оформление `TextView`. Как поменять полностью все разделы? Если поменять напрямую в разметке `TextView`:

с

```
 android:background="@drawable/head"
```

на

```
 android:background="@drawable/minus"
```

то все работает.

Comment: Мало что понятно. У вас в меню ListView с этими TextView в качестве элементов?

Comment: Да, именно так. ExpandableListView

Answer (score 1):

Менять содержимое списочных элементов надо не напрямую обращаясь к разметке, а через адаптер, изменив в нём значение к-л переменной, от коей зависит отрисовка элемента разметки в адаптере.

Т.е.

1. В адаптере заведите переменную типа `boolean`.
2. В зависимости от её значения устанавливайте в методе отрисовки адаптера `getView`/`getChildView`/`getGroupView` нужный фон для `TextView`
3. В адаптрере же установите метод для смены значения этой переменной.
4. При нажтии на кнопку меню вызовите метод изменения значения переменной адаптера и заставьте его перерисоваться вызовом метода `notifyDataSetChanged()`

---

Ваш способ не работает, т.к. вы по ID находите всегда только один элемент разметки, а их у вас много с одним и тем же ID в списке. Потому и меняется всего один элемент